# How to describe a sample space?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Question:**

A examiner marks $150$ exam papers giving a mark from $1$ to $100$.

How would I design a sample space for the experiment?

My problem is I'm not sure exactly what the question is asking me, does it want me to find a way to describe the sample space or am I missing the point entirely?

If so wouldn't it just be the set $\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_{150}):x_i\in \{1,...,100\}\}$.

It seems like I am missing something? Why would it ask me to design a sample space isn't the sample space just all possible outcomes I don't understand the word "design" here.

Comment: I think your answer is correct.  I don't think you're missing anything.

Comment: Okay then thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is *a* reasonable sample space.

The set you describe is also represented as a Cartesian power: $$\{1,...,100\}^{150} ~=~ \{(x_1,...,x_{150}): x_i\in\{1,...,100\}\}$$